# Translate woocommerce totally in french

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, translate

I make an ecommerce site with wordpress and I have to translate it totally in french but unfortunately many parts are not translated into french yet i use woocommerce for french.

website : https://babygnon.com/ Template : Kidtyshop Downloaded : theme monster

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question, it's a work request

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the quickest/simplest approach in your case is to use a plugin such as [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to manually update missing translations. I have had similar issues and was able to fix them with that plugin.